# How to create a custom control with INamingContainer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controltemplate, naming-containers

I am trying the following:

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[TemplateContainer(typeof(TemplateContainer))]
public virtual ITemplate LayoutTemplate { get; set; }

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Clear();

    if (LayoutTemplate != null)
    {
        var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);

        foreach (int index in data)
        {
            TemplateContainer container = new TemplateContainer(index);

            LayoutTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);

            this.Controls.Add(container);
        }
    }
}
```

My container class:

```
public class TemplateContainer : Control, INamingContainer
{
    public int Index { get; set; }

    internal TemplateContainer(int index)
    {
        this.Index = index;
    }
}
```

And my markup:

```
<uc:TemplateControl ID="ucTemplateControl" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <b>Index:</b>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Literal1" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Container.Index %>'
            ReadOnly="true" />
        <br />
    </LayoutTemplate>
</uc:TemplateControl>
```

But for some reason `Container.Index` is not rendering any value, just empty. 10 controls are being created, but none shows a value.

What did I do wrong? How can I fix it so it will show the `Index` value?

I tried something similar to MSDN example:

- [How to: Create Templated ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Full control file: https://github.com/brunolm/Exam-70-515/blob/master/WebApplication/Ch07/TemplateControl.ascx.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind the value you need to call the `DataBind` method of the custom control.

Calling

```
ucTemplateControl.DataBind();
```

from the page made the data to be bound on the template.